# Django - Search for existence of 'slug' in multiple models

Tags: python, django

I want to search for the existence of slug in multiple models at once in django, right now i have to search through all of them one by one. Is there any method to search through all models at once?

Comment: can you show your search code? Do you use postgres? then you can use full-text search

Comment: From what I see, you have multiple models with same field 'slug'. You need to use contenttype framework provided by Django.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such method. You can implement it yourself:

```
def filter_by_slug(models, slug):
    results = []
    for model in models:
        results.extend(model.objects.filter(slug=slug))
    return results
```

Use it like this:

```
>>> filter_by_slug([MyModel, AnotherModel], 'the_slug')
```

More generalized:

```
def filter_all(models, **query):
    results = []
    for model in models:
        results.extend(model.objects.filter(query))
    return results
```

Which you can use like this:

```
>>> filter_by_slug([MyModel, AnotherModel], slug='the_slug')
```

A few things worth noting:

- this will perform one database query per model
- both methods fetch all matching objects for all models
- the result is a list, not a queryset